# Do I need to update references?

Tags: c#

I updated a library project method,

```
public static void EatFruit(string a, string b)
```

to

```
public static void EatFruit(string a, string b, bool IsEatFruit = false)
```

Now there are hundred of projects using this library, Do I need to update references of library dll in all projects and solutions ?

I updated the server and they all are failing by this error,

> Method not found void EatFruit(System.String, System.String)'.

Comment: Even if is an optional param you will have to update the references.

Comment: how come you can't just add this as a new method because the signatures are different `public static void EatFruit(string a, string b, bool IsEatFruit = false)` you would just need to update the reference and the existing code should still function properly
and to answer your question yes you would need to update the reference..

Comment: Remember that optional parameters are a compile-time feature.

Comment: [C# Optional Parameters in Library Code](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/DefaultParameterProblem.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you need to update it there.

There is a possible solution by just making the new method overload and forcing the old one to call it.

Just do the following:

```
public static void EatFruit(string a, string b)
{
    EatFruit(a,b,false);
}

public static void EatFruit(string a, string b,  bool IsEatFruit = false)
```

Answer (score 11):

> Do I need to update references of library dll in all projects and solutions ?

Yes.  C# is a statically typed language and you've changed the method signature.  You might try a slightly different refactoring approach here and just add the new functionality instead of replacing existing functionality:

```
public static void EatFruit(string a, string b)
{
    // change the BODY of the existing method,
    // but not its SIGNATURE.
    EatFruit(a, b, false);
}

public static void EatFruit(string a, string b, bool IsEatFruit)
{
    // move the BODY of the existing method here.
    // this is a NEW method unknown to existing clients.
}
```

With this approach you wouldn't need to update existing clients because they can still call the same method with the same signature.  New clients will also be able to call the new method, though.

Comment: `+`1`Excellent explanation David

Comment: Also one could tag the old one with `[Obsolete]` to let consumers know about the change

Answer (score 2):

If old projects don't need `IsEatFruit` parameter simply use two functions in your library project:

- `public static void EatFruit(string a, string b)`
- `public static void EatFruit(string a, string b, bool IsEatFruit = false)`

Answer (score 0):

Even if is an optional param you will have to update the references, if you don't want to do it just create the new method.

```
    public static void EatFruit(string a, string b)
    {
    }

    public static void EatFruit(string a, string b, bool IsEatFruit = false)
    {
    }
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)